# Can an employer determine benefits eligibility based on home address?

Tags: employment

Say someone lives in county A, which is in the same state as county B. The Employer, based in the same state as both counties, offers different health insurance plans to someone living in county A than they offer to someone living in county B, even though both people are doing the same job (same job title, same responsibilities, same level) in the same geographic location. The costs of the health insurance appear to be the same (at least to the employee), but one could argue the plan offered to a person living in county A is better based on the flexibility available within the plan.

Can the employer deny eligibility to the person who lives in county B? If not, what statutes or legal arguments support this perspective?

Answer (score 2):

Federally yes :

The Equal protection clause of the 14th amendment doesn't apply to private businesses and the discrimination clause of the [Civil Rights Act of 1964 - Title II](https://www.justice.gov/crt/title-ii-civil-rights-act-public-accommodations) :

> **42 U.S.C. §2000a (a)** All persons shall be entitled to the full and equal enjoyment of the goods, services, facilities, privileges, advantages, and accommodations of any place of public accommodation, as defined in this section, without discrimination on the ground of **race, color, religion, or national origin**.

National origin, being discrimination based on one's or one's ancestor origin, *could* apply in some cases but probably not most